# Not a Valid Identifier

Tags: ros, bashrc, package, path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the tutorial found on the book Learning ROS by Martinez page 40. When creating a new workspace, after adding a folder and trying to add this path to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH I keep getting the following:

```
bash: export: `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH~/dev/rosbook:/opt/ros/kinetic/share:/opt/ros/kinetic/stacks': not a valid identifier
```

These are the commands:

```
clare@clare-VirtualBox:~$ echo "export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH"~/dev/rosbook:${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH} >> ~/.bashrc
clare@clare-VirtualBox:~$ . ~/.bashrc
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244197/not-a-valid-identifier/) by [csal](https://answers.ros.org/users/28037/csal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-09-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MuratAhmetGenc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27751/muratahmetgenc/) on 2016-09-25**:
that line you're trying to run, is from the book Aaron wrote right? I got the same problem. looks like the book is pretty old and not gonna work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First: don't do what you are trying to do. It is unnecessary to manually edit the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`. It will automatically be updated to include the proper paths whenever you *source* your target workspace (which in your case I'm guessing is located at `~/dev/rosbook`.

After building your workspace, do a `source ~/dev/rosbook/devel/setup.bash`. That will setup the correct paths.

Second: if you really want to do this, notice that you are missing a `=` (equals) between `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` and `~/dev/rosbook`. That most likely leads `bash` to interpret the entire line as the *name* of the environment variable that you are trying to set. It then notices that that name includes some illegal characters (ie: characters that cannot be part of an environment variable's name), and thus it prints that error message.

To fix it: open your `.bashrc`, locate the line that starts with `export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` and insert the `=`. Save, resource.

But note that I don't recommend manually changing `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3